# Не работает скрипт на сайте. Cannot read property 'innerText' of null

Tags: javascript

В общем мне нужно, чтоб в рекламный баннер подставлялся текст, который содержится вне баннера. Есть возможность разместить только html код баннера на сайт через рекламный сервис, доступа к коду сайта нет.
В песочнице и на локалке все работает, а когда заливаю баннер на сайт то получаю ошибку Cannot read property 'innerText' of null.

```js
   let div1IH = document.getElementById("user-block-toggle");
console.log(div1IH);
let div1IT = document.getElementById("user-block-toggle").innerText;
console.log(div1IT);
document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = div1IT;
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="imgcont">
        <a id="user-block-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    <p class="user-pic">  
    <img src="https://doctor.mis.sdh.com.ua/static/img/medstar/doctor-female-icon.jpg" alt="Image" class="media-box-object img-circle thumb42 med-img-border med-user-pic">
                    </p>
                    <p class="user-info">
                      <span class="user-block-name">&#1055;&#1077;&#1090;&#1088;&#1077;&#1085;&#1082;&#1086; &#1054;.&#1054;.</span>
                      <span class="user-block-role">&#1057;&#1110;&#1084;&#1077;&#1081;&#1085;&#1080;&#1081; &#1083;&#1110;&#1082;&#1072;&#1088;</span>
                    </p>
                    <em class="icon-toggle"></em>
                  </a>
        
        <div class="img" style="position:relative; width: 204px; height: 365px; background-image: url(https://medstar.ua/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/banner.jpg);"><div class="obr" id="c" style="position: absolute; left: 20px; top:20px;">Василь Васильович</div></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: надо дождаться загрузки страницы и только потом выполнять код. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего на момент срабатывания скрипта, user-block-toggle ещё не существует.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   let div1IH = document.getElementById("user-block-toggle");
   console.log(div1IH);
   let div1IT = document.getElementById("user-block-toggle").textContent;
   console.log(div1IT);
   document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = div1IT;
});
```

И вместо `innerText` лучше использовать `textContent`, чтобы было кроссбраузерно

Comment: Спасибо) А как можно отложить загрузку?

Comment: Вот как раз в моём коде пример - обёртка в обработчик "DOMContentLoaded"

Comment: Все равно ошибка с Вашим кодом. `VM1738:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:5:61)
    at aC (ef5712e7.js:1)
    at ef5712e7.js:1
    at XMLHttpRequest.U.aH.onreadystatechange (ef5712e7.js:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.d (raven.js:445)
(anonymous) @ VM1738:5
aC @ ef5712e7.js:1
(anonymous) @ ef5712e7.js:1
U.aH.onreadystatechange @ ef5712e7.js:1
d @ raven.js:445`

Comment: Вы уверены, что элемент с `id="user-block-toggle"` есть на странице?